# From container to container-fluid on XS devices

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I saw one question in this subject - but the answer there doesn't works.

So, as I said in the title, I have a page with `<div class="container">`. I want that in **extra-small devices (767px)**, this `container` will become to `container-fluid`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the Bootstrap CSS file, the `.container` class only starts using fixed widths from `768px` upwards - below that (**767px and below**), it simply spans **100%** of its parent, exactly the same as `container-fluid` (default div behaivour albeit with 15px of padding either side):

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
```

In other words, on the face of it, it's pretty pointless if you ask me as the following style applies at all viewports:

```
.container, .container-fluid {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

And since .container widths don't kick in until 768px and upwards, as you can see `container` and `container-fluid` are styled exactly the same below 767px.

EDIT - further to OP's comments, to remove the padding from the left / right side of container, I would first append a secondary class to your container div:

```
<div class="container nopadding">
```

This ensures you don't overwrite Bootstrap's default styling. You can then style as follows:

```
.container.nopadding {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Important to ensure that the above style is placed in your custom CSS file and that it referenced **AFTER** your Bootstrap files.

Comment: This is a bad solution because If I will continue minimize my browser, it will stack on width: 750px forever and my website will not be responsive...

Comment: Its not a solution at all - I'm simply stating what happens - using either container-fluid or container below 767px makes absolutely no difference whatsoever.

Comment: That's the 15px of padding that both container and container-fluid add in by default on both the left and right hand side.... I'll edit my answer to remove the padding if thats what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: No, nevermind, I just thought that its possible to reach all the screen, but I'll be good without it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: No problem - I've added another bit to my answer anyway so feel free to use as you please :-)

Answer (score 2):

**with jquery you can control it :**
remove `container` class when `window.innerWidth` is lower than 767 (e.g:any size that you want)and add class `container-fluid`

```
 $( function() {
if(window.innerWidth <767)
    {
        $(".container").addClass('container-fluid');
        $(".container").removeClass('container');
    }
});
```

**when user changes window size :**

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
    if(window.innerWidth <767)
    {
        $(".container").addClass('container-fluid');
        $(".container").removeClass('container');
    }else
    {
        $(".container-fluid").addClass('container');
        $(".container-fluid").removeClass('container-fluid');
    }
});
```